# Typescript extend react native View component

Tags: typescript, react-native, typescript-typings

Trying to extend `react-native` `View` component. However I'm having trouble extending props of the View component.

Here is how I extend the `Props`

```
import { StyleSheet, View, ViewStyle, ViewProps } from "react-native";
interface Props extends ViewProps {
  pb?: keyof Size | number;
  pt?: keyof Size | number;
  pv?: keyof Size | number;
  ph?: keyof Size | number;
}
```

Here is my custom `View` component

```
class WrappedView extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    const methods = {};
    let { style: attrStyles, children, pb, pt, pv, ph, ...rest } = this.props;
    let style = [attrStyles];
    // Shorthand prop styles
    let propStyles: ViewStyle = {};
    propStyles.paddingBottom = pb;
    propStyles.paddingTop = pt;
    propStyles.paddingVertical = pv;
    propStyles.paddingHorizontal = ph;
    style.push(propStyles);
    return (
      <View style={style} {...rest} {...this.state} {...methods}>
        {children}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

When I try a test like so

```
const test = () => {
  return <WrappedView pb={"large"} width={"100%"} />;
};
```

I get the following issue

```
Type '{ pb: "large"; width: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<WrappedView> & Readonly<Props> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.
  Property 'width' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<WrappedView> & Readonly<Props> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.
```

Comment: `width` is not a prop from `ViewProps`. Check it [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html)

Comment: Argh this is pretty embarrassing thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in the question does indeed extend the props correctly instead it was a client mistake. The client should read:

```
const test = () => {
  return <WrappedView pb={"large"} style={{width:"100%"}} />;
};
```

Comment: Exactly. Note that you don't need to redefine `style` prop in your `interface Props extends ViewProps` as you did in the question, 'cause style is already a `ViewProp`.